# Passing a rendered JSP fragment as an argument to another JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a JSP fragment that looks like this:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <h1>Hello Everyone!</h1> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <jsp:include page="./anotherJspFragment.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="someName" value="someValue"/>
        </jsp:include>
    </div>
</div>
```

This fragment is repeated several times within a JSP page - it has been copied and pasted, with only the parts labelled '1' and '2' changing between each occurrence.

Each instance of this fragment `include`s a different JSP page, with different arguments.

Some look like this:

```
        <jsp:include page="./firstJspFragment.jsp" />
```

While others look like this:

```
        <jsp:include page="./secondJspFragment.jsp">
            <jsp:param name="someName1" value="someValue1"/>
            <jsp:param name="someName2" value="someValue2"/>
        </jsp:include>
```

I would like to create a reusable JSP fragment that contains all the boilerplate markup, which I can use to reduce the duplication. This JSP fragment would need to take a rendered JSP fragment as an argument (`firstJspFragment.jsp` or `secondJspFragment.jsp`, etc). Is this possible? Or is there some other approach I can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like the way to do this is to create a tag in `WEB-INF/tags` called e.g. `myTag.tag` which contains the boilerplate markup

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags5.html

You can then pass the rendered page in as the body, e.g.

```
<test:myTag title="Hello Everyone">
    <jsp:include page="./firstJspFragment.jsp" />
</test:myTag>
```

This JSP fragment will then be rendered at the point in the tag where `<jsp:doBody />` occurrs, e.g.

```
<%@ attribute name="title" required="true" %>

<div>
    <div>
        <!-- 1 -->
        <h1>${title}</h1> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <!-- 2 -->
        <jsp:doBody />
    </div>
</div>
```